# How to switch a component in html template using routeProvider in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, components, route-provider

The question already says it. My code looks like that:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

angular.module("homeApp", ["ngRoute", "componentsApp"])
.config(["$routeProvider",
function ($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider.when("/", {
    templateUrl: "/modules/home/index.html"
  });

  $routeProvider.when("/about", {
    templateUrl: "/modules/home/about.html"
  });

  $routeProvider.when("/contact", {
    templateUrl: "/modules/home/contact.html"
  });

  $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
}]);
})();
```

Instead of calling a new html template I want just to switch out one element in my index.html template with an component in the componentsApp. I know I can do it with ngSwitch without even using the routeProvider but is there a way with?